# Sympy factoring in Python

Tags: python, sympy

If I have obtained the following equation using Sympy:

[image]

Is it possible to arrange the variables so that x and L appear only as x/L in the equation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting `x/L` by another symbol (e.g. `y`) seems to work for me:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> x, L, u, nu, y = sp.symbols('x L u nu y')
>>> expr = 0.45*nu/u**6/(1-x/L)**6 * (u**5*x - 5*u**5*x**2/2/L + 10*u**5*x**3/3/L**2 - 5*u**5*x**4/2/L**3 + u**5*x**5/L**4 - u**5*x**6/6/L**5)
>>> sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
>>> expr
       ⎛          5  2       5  3      5  4    5  5    5  6⎞
       ⎜ 5     5⋅u ⋅x    10⋅u ⋅x    5⋅u ⋅x    u ⋅x    u ⋅x ⎟
0.45⋅ν⋅⎜u ⋅x - ─────── + ──────── - ─────── + ───── - ─────⎟
       ⎜         2⋅L          2          3       4        5⎟
       ⎝                   3⋅L        2⋅L       L      6⋅L ⎠
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                  6                         
                         6 ⎛    x⎞                          
                        u ⋅⎜1 - ─⎟                          
                           ⎝    L⎠                          
>>> expr2 = expr.subs(x/L, y)
>>> expr2
       ⎛   5    5                5    3       5    2      5           ⎞
       ⎜  u ⋅x⋅y     5    4   5⋅u ⋅x⋅y    10⋅u ⋅x⋅y    5⋅u ⋅x⋅y    5  ⎟
0.45⋅ν⋅⎜- ─────── + u ⋅x⋅y  - ───────── + ────────── - ──────── + u ⋅x⎟
       ⎝     6                    2           3           2           ⎠
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                               6         6                             
                              u ⋅(-y + 1)                              
>>> expr2.collect(x*u**5)
         ⎛   5           3       2          ⎞
         ⎜  y     4   5⋅y    10⋅y    5⋅y    ⎟
0.45⋅ν⋅x⋅⎜- ── + y  - ──── + ───── - ─── + 1⎟
         ⎝  6          2       3      2     ⎠
─────────────────────────────────────────────
                           6                 
                 u⋅(-y + 1)                  
>>>
```

If you really want it to display with a symbol of `(x/L)`, you'll need to define that and resubstitute it:

```
>>> s = sp.symbols('(x/L)')
>>> expr2.collect(x*u**5).subs(y, s)
         ⎛       5                   3           2              ⎞
         ⎜  (x/L)         4   5⋅(x/L)    10⋅(x/L)    5⋅(x/L)    ⎟
0.45⋅ν⋅x⋅⎜- ────── + (x/L)  - ──────── + ───────── - ─────── + 1⎟
         ⎝    6                  2           3          2       ⎠
─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                       6                         
                         u⋅(-(x/L) + 1)
```

Comment: Thank you @OliverW. but there is still a 'x' in the '0.45vx' term!

Comment: If you look at your original equation, you'll see you cannot cancel it out.